# Python: Pandas dataframe - data overwritten instead of concatinated

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to extract data from several .csv files and combine them into one big dataframe in pandas.To do this I created one dataframe that should be filled with the data of the incoming dataframes.

```
final_df = DataFrame(columns=['Column1','Column2','Column3'])

for file in glob.glob("file.csv"):
     name_csv = str(file)
     logfile = pd.read_csv(name_csv, skip_blank_lines = False)
     df = DataFrame(logFile, columns=['Column1','Column2','Column3']
     concat = pd.concat([final_df,df])
```

However, with every iteration through the loop, the previously extracted data is overwritten. How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need first `append` all `df` to `list` and then use [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html):

Also some improvement to [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) - `logfile` is already df, better is use parameter `names`.

```
dfs = []
for file in glob.glob("*.csv"):
     logfile = pd.read_csv(str(file), 
                           skip_blank_lines = False, 
                           names = ['Column1','Column2','Column3'])
     dfs.append(logfile)

concat = pd.concat(dfs)
```

Or use `list comprehension`:

```
dfs = [pd.read_csv(str(file), 
       skip_blank_lines = False, 
       names = ['Column1','Column2','Column3']) for file in glob.glob("*.csv")]

concat = pd.concat(dfs)
```

Comment: Looks like parens are wrong in your list comprehension.

Answer (score 2):

You are not using the result of `pd.concat` at all. The variable `concat` is just thrown away in each iteration, but it would be the partial data frame.

Answer (score 1):

You should create the list of the df's and concat it all at the end:

```
concat_list = [] 
for file in glob.glob("file.csv"):
     name_csv = str(file)
     logfile = pd.read_csv(name_csv, skip_blank_lines = False)
     df = DataFrame(logFile, columns=['Column1','Column2','Column3']
     concat_list.appned(df)
final_df = pd.concat(concat_list)
```

Comment: There's no reason to keep the first instance of `final_df` in this case. It just get's replaced in the end.

Comment: @languitar , Forgot to delete it, Thanks :)